# How to categorize a text string based on keywords in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on creating a macro using VBA to read a long list of columns (approximately 11,000) and assign each row to a "category" by finding keywords within the text in each cell. The text in each file is related to a warranty claim, and the idea is by determining is a cell has 3 or 4 matches from a list of "keywords" it can be lumped into a bucket.

Below is the code I am trying to use right now. Where I am running into issues, is if I try to create a list of additional keywords ("injector" is current keyword below) and  edit the > function afterwards to be a number greater than zero.

The code below is working for single keywords.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 28 Then
        If InStr(1, UCase(Target.Value), "INJECTOR") > 0 Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 53) = "DEF leak from tip"
        End If
        If InStr(1, UCase(Target.Value), "HARNESS") > 0 Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 53) = "Internal DEF leak affecting wire harness"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Example of what I am looking to do:

[image]

Comment: You could add an OR to your if statement. If InStr(1, UCase(Target.Value), "INJECTOR") > 0 OR InStr(1, UCase(Target.Value), "ITEM3") > 0 OR InStr(1, UCase(Target.Value), "ITEM2") > 0 Then

Comment: how about Select Case statement?

Comment: I am not familiar with Select Case statement, how would that would with this specific application?

Comment: @hooded0ne, I am not sure that the "or" statements would work since it would limit selecting multiples at once. For example, if the text string contained "a, b, c, d, e" and we can classify this text as category "x" if the text contains any combination of 3 letters from "a, b, c, d, e". Using or, we could not specify a combination of the three

Comment: How long might the lists of keywords be from which 3 or 4 items should be matched before an item is given a specific classification?

Comment: Hi Tim, the keyword list for each category is between 7-10

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible approach:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim v, classn
    
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 28 Then Exit Sub
    
    v = Target.Value
    If Len(v) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    'would be better to keep these lists and classifications on a worksheet and get them from there...
    If MatchCount("injector,item2,item3", v) > 1 Then classn = "DEF leak from tip"
    If MatchCount("item4,item5,item6", v) > 1 Then classn = "other thing"
    'etc
    
    Target.EntireRow.Cells(53).Value = classn

End Sub

Function MatchCount(lst As String, txt)
    Dim arr, e, n As Long
    arr = Split(lst, ",") 'get array from list
    For Each e In arr
        n = n + IIf(InStr(txt, e) > 0, 1, 0) 'track match count
    Next e
    MatchCount = n
End Function
```

Instead of hard-coding keywords and classifications in the event handler, you could consider storing them on a worksheet and reading them from there.